# How to make library's transitive dependencies show up in app when using BillOfMaterials?

Tags: android, gradle, dependency-management, maven-bom

I find that transitive dependencies of my library does not show up in app, especially when maven BoM is used in my library.

When there is no BoM, transitive dependency appear in app. Here is the illustration of the case where 3rd-party-lib shows up correctly as runtime dependency in my-app.

```
[my-app] --> [my-lib] --> [3rd-party-lib]
```

But when I use BoM in my library (illustrated below), it does not show up as runtime dependency in my-app. This causes crash at runtime!

```
[my-app] --> [my-lib] --> [bom] --> [3rd-party-lib]
```

Here is the code with which this problem is reproducible:

```
// bom/build.gradle

plugins {
    id 'java-platform'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        bom(MavenPublication) {
            from components.javaPlatform
        }
    }
}

group "com.example"
version "0.0.3"

dependencies {
    constraints {
        api "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1" // 3rd-party-lib
    }
}
```

```
// mylibrary/build.gradle

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
<<removed stuff for brevity>>

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'

    api platform("com.example:bom:0.0.3")
    api "com.jakewharton.timber:timber"
}

// This helps to publish this library to maven local.
apply from: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sky-uk/gradle-maven-plugin/1.0.4/gradle-mavenizer.gradle"
```

```
// myapp/build.gradle

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
<<removed stuff for brevity>>

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'

    implementation "com.example:mylibrary:1.0.0"
}
```

In this case, timber is the 3rd-party-lib. As mentioned, this does not show up in app when mylibrary uses BoM. As a result, app crashes whenever app calls mylibrary code that internally requires timber.

How do I ensure mylibrary brings in transitive dependencies to app?

PS: I publish to mylibrary to maven local.

Answer (score 1):

This is working as intended, as Maven [transitive dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) reads (which also applies to Gradle):

> Maven avoids the need to discover and specify the libraries that your own dependencies require by including transitive dependencies automatically.

If you'd really like to force it, you could *theoretically* `exclude` them from the Gradle dependency and instead add them as individual (non-transitive) dependencies - but that's not required. This only makes sense, eg. when intending to provide a newer version - or when working against version conflicts. If the goal is to have self-contained offline projects, there are [other ways](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/331817/self-contained-projects-gradle-maven-dependencies-offline).

Answer (score 1):

My unverified(!) guess would be that this [“Gradle Maven Plugin”](https://github.com/sky-uk/gradle-maven-plugin) that you apply to your library could be the culprit. It [performs some mangling](https://github.com/sky-uk/gradle-maven-plugin/blob/3ec7c8b7dbb62b554045e4a953b33ce8c7bc5af8/artifact-pom-manager.gradle) of the dependencies recorded in the published POM which might be bogous for BOMs.

FWIW, the whole setup works for me without this plugin (and a plain Java library/application for lack of an Android SDK on my current computer). Below you can find the (full) working setup.

I know, this may not be an accurate answer. Maybe it’ll still help you track down the issue.

### Minimal Working Setup

```
.
├── bom
│   └── build.gradle
├── myapp
│   └── build.gradle
└── mylibrary
    └── build.gradle
```

#### `bom/build.gradle`

has the exact same content as in the question

#### `mylibrary/build.gradle`

```java
apply plugin: 'java-library'

group "com.example"
version "1.0.0"

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    api platform("com.example:bom:0.0.3")
    api "com.jakewharton.timber:timber"
}
```

#### `myapp/build.gradle`

```java
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.example:mylibrary:1.0.0"
}
```

### Check that it Works

Run this from the `myapp/` directory (using a Gradle 6.1.1 Wrapper not included above):

```sh
./gradlew dependencies --include-build ../mylibrary/ --include-build ../bom/
```

Comment: can you please help in this https://stackoverflow.com/q/77935207/8926845